# Duda sobre un simple juego de piedra papel tijeras lagarto spock!

Tags: java, game

De un array estático en el que tengo {piedra,papel,tijera,lagarto,spock}
me interesa que el ordenador coja uno aleatoriamente. ¿Como haría?

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            menuprin();
        }

    }

    private static int scanner() {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        return sc.nextInt();
    }

    private static void menuprin() {
        System.out.println(
                "PIEDRA PAPEL TIJERAS LAGARTO SPOCK\r\n" + "1. Jugar\r\n" + "0. Salir\r\n" + "Escoja una opción:");
        int opcion = scanner();
        switch (opcion) {
        case 0:
            System.exit(0);
            break;
        case 1:
            jugar();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("No es una opción válida.");
            break;
        }
    }

    private static void jugar() {
        System.out.println("Escriba su jugada piedra, papel, tijeras,lagarto, Spock:");
        String cosa = scannercosa();


    }

    private static String scannercosa() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        return sc.nextLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema exacto?

Comment: La clase [Random](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) es lo que necesitas: `Random r = new Random(); int index = r.nextInt(opciones.length);`

Comment: Te recomiendo que la pregunta la hagas de una forma que el usuario solo tenga que introducir una letra o un numero (mejor si es numero para luego usar la clase Random como te he dicho Pablo Lozano justo encima.

Comment: Tu profesor es Fernando seguro xD

Comment: Por favor incluye el código de tu array estático.